# How to build an iOS framework using xcodebuild?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, ios-frameworks

Trying to build my iOS framework from the command line, I get "MyFramework.framework.xcarchive" instead of "MyFramework.framework".

I get the proper result when building within Xcode, just not from the command line.

My command to build is really simple:

```
xcodebuild -project myFramework.xcodeproj -scheme myScheme -archivePath "/dev/builds" archive
```

Where is my '.framework' file?

Answer (score 5):

I think you don't get build result in form of .framework because you're passing excessive *archive* parameter. Normally to build framework such command should work:

```
$ xcodebuild -project TestFramework.xcodeproj -scheme TestFramework -configuration Release -sdk macosx CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=. clean build
```

Note that in this example build directory is current one. As a result you'll get two build flavours: *TestFramework.framework* and *TestFramework.framework.dSYM*

Comment: Hmm. With this technique I don't get any output, not even the incorrect *.xcarchive file.  Not sure if this matters, but just in case -- the command line is being executed as the sole step in a TeamCity build.

Comment: I think the issue is I want the PRODUCT, not the Archive.  That's why setting "-archivePath" doesn't really help.  But looking at the 'xcodebuild' documentation, I don't see a way to set the Product Output directory.

Comment: Hi @Bungles, did you find your answer?

Comment: I did find a solution eventually, but it's been so long I don't recall the details. Sorry...

Comment: @WizardofKneup, this might be what you are looking for https://medium.com/@german.velibekov_7849/how-to-create-ios-fat-frameworks-libraries-and-thin-c20c2f7e00f0